# Syncing a cell from an outside sheet to multiple rows in the master sheet with IMPORTRANGE, SPLIT, TRANSPOSE

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I am having issues with syncing some data from an outside spreadsheet to a master spreadsheet. The problem lies in the fact that there are multiple strings in each cell of the column I wish to sync. I have tried to solve the problem by using IMPORTRANGE to get the data from the I column (starting at I2 onwards), then splitting the strings and finally transposing them to get them into rows, which works well for the master sheet. I have written it like so:

={TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","sheet_name!I2:I"),","))}

The problem is in the fact that this formula only works for the first cell (I2), despite the fact that I have specified the entire I column. It gets the correct range of data, but when I use SPLIT on it, it only takes the first one into account.

What am I missing? Is there a way to include a new row as a delimiter also in the SPLIT function and in which way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","sheet_name!I2:I"),","))})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The formula is working, but it displays the transposed values from each cell in separate columns, while I wish to display them all in the same column, one beneath the other. 

I will try to find the solution by myself, but if you have any idea about it, it would be much appreciated :)

Thanks again for helping a novice like me.

Comment: @ToniVitali can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?